# How to make HTML page responsive?

Tags: html, resize, size, zooming, scale

I want my webpage to look something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2VKf.jpg no matter what browser I use (opera, chrome, firefox etc), but I don't know how to do that. And more than that, I have a second problem (which I think is bigger) when trying to resize the window or zoom the page. I recorded it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qcy-VIRAfY&feature=youtu.be

This is my code: https://justpaste.it/6co8x (the things which are not relevant are bolded).

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

About your page, I would suggest for you first that you use a css grid or flexbox as an elegant, responsivness way to style your components, and maybe you can start by this article if you don't have ideas about it:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-css-grid-in-5-minutes-f582e87b1228

after that I would suggest that you use some media queries in either your HTML or CSS/SASS code, maybe something like this can help:

https://medium.com/@clergemarvin/create-a-responsive-site-using-css-media-queries-d56e39a892e6

PS: you can get rid of media queries using css grid elements. hope it helps ;)